# How to find in postgres whether a view column is nullable or not

Tags: postgresql

In postgres is there way to form a query using system tables where we pass the view name and column name and it gives whether that column nullable.

Answer (score 2):

Appreciate that a column appearing inside is a view is backed by a column in the underlying table behind the view.  So, if we can determine whether a table's column is nullable, it should suffice for your question.  We can try the following query:

```sql
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'yourTable';
```

If you don't know the table name, you may run the following command from the Postgres command line:

```
\sv your_view_name_here
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do that. View definitions are stored as parsed trees (data type `pg_node_tree`), and there is no good way to handle these in SQL.

For the related question why view columns are always nullable in PostgreSQL, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17301323/6464308).

You could write a C extension that analyzes the view definition, and if a column is defined from a table column and there are no outer joins, you could deduce the nullability of the view column from that of the table column. But that is not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "trail and error" approach that may help **(SQLi unsafe)**.
Assuming that the view (or table) has an unique `id` column and at least one row then try to update and see what is happening. The test table, view and function are defined as temporary in the illustration below.

```sql
-- prepare the test ground
create temporary table tt (id integer not null unique, v integer);
create temporary view tv as select * from tt;
insert into tv values (1, 2), (2, null);

create or replace function pg_temp.nullable(tabname text, colname text) 
returns boolean language plpgsql as 
$$
declare 
    retval boolean := false;
begin
    begin   
      execute format ('update %1$I set %2$I = null where id = (select id from %1$I limit 1)', tabname, colname);
      retval := true;
      raise exception 'Ignored'; -- rollback the update
    exception when others then null;
    end;
    return retval;
end;
$$;

-- test
select pg_temp.nullable('tv', 'id'); -- result false
select pg_temp.nullable('tv', 'v');  -- result true

discard all;
```